# Картинка не отображается в django

Tags: python, django, изображения

У меня не отображается картинка в django,
но если делать это через admin то все работает.

мне нужно что бы это делал пользователь а не администратор

кто знает в чем проблема?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

from account.models import Profile


class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

     author = Profile.user

     body = models.TextField()

     published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     img = models.ImageField(
         blank=True, upload_to='images/blog/%Y/%m/%d', 
         help_text='150x150px', 
         verbose_name='Ссылка картинки'
     )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def image_img(self):
        if self.image:
        return u'<a href="{0}" target="_blank"><img src="{0}" 
               width="100"/></a>'.format(self.image.url)
    else:
        return '(Нет изображения)'

    image_img.short_description = 'Картинка'
    image_img.allow_tags = True
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, 
UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'


class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    template_name = 'post_detail.html'


class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = '__all__'


class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'img']


class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

html

```css
.post {
    border: 2px outset #ffde00;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.card-body {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}

        <div class="post mb-5">
            <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}" style="text-decoration: none; color: #4f4f4f;">
                {% if post.img %}
                    <img id="img-post-home" height="200" width="300" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.img.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt=' Тут должна быть'>
            
                {% else %}
                    <img src="/media/defualt/нет-фото-300x300.png" height="200" width="300">
                {% endif %}
                
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ post.body }}</p>
                    <p>{{ post.published }}</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Либо `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.img }}`, либо `{{ post.img.url }}`

Comment: проверил оба, не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

было

```html
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

стало

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

и все заработало

все во то надо было добавить enctype="multipart/form-data"
в тег form

Comment: Тогда неправильно сформулирован вопрос был

Comment: Я не знал о том что это было нужно(

Comment: Я бы не смог сформулировать вопрос если не знаю в чем именно проблема, и там же ответ мне показал ментор на учебе, я не нашел ответ сам.